How do I know if I've been possessed by a jinn?
Asalam alaikum hope everyone is well . So I am a former drug addict and I used to mess with the occult so now I'm worried a jinn or a devil has possessed me cuz I was diagnosed with skitzo effective disorder because of audio and visual hullucinations. I usually see figures in the shadows that are either Dominic looking or have no faces or disfigured. Does this sound like jinn possession? And even with meds they still appear so I'm getting really worried

Alongside medication use Ruqyah, that is beneficial regardless of whether the reason is medical or demonic.

I cannot tell if you see things that are not there, or if you see things that are there but others cannot see. Go and find some doctor or counselor. Not one of the over-scientific that deny anything that they cannot measure with their instruments, but also not a Voodoo-Hungan. Do you know a Mufti that also has some medical knowledge?

Thanks for the suggestions I do see a therapist but I struggle so bad at times I can't even leave my room. This has happened sense I messed with the occult that why I thought I was possessed by something

How did you mess with the occult?

I was a satanist before and did rituals with supposed friends. I even pledged my allegiance to the devil. Now I'm really scared that's why I see things others dont
